# SQL: Check Constraints to force a regex of arbitrary length?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, check-constraints

I'm new to regex and I'm using Postgres. I'm trying to make a check constraint in a table so that any data into some column always checks for only alphanumeric, numeric, alphanumeric without spaces, etc.

For example, given a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE client (
PRIMARY KEY (id),
id                  CHAR(18)    NOT NULL,
name                TEXT        NOT NULL,
promo_code          TEXT        NOT NULL
);
```

I'd like to make a constraint with a CHECK that only allows alphanumeric without spaces content in id, alphabetic with spaces in name, alphanumeric with symbols without spaces content in promo_code.
id has a strict length of 18, but name and promo_code have variable length.

Would something like the following work?

```
ALTER TABLE client
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_client_one
    CHECK (
        id ~ '%\w%' AND id !~ '%\s%',
        name ~ '%\w%' AND name !~ '%\d%',
        promo_code ~ '%\w%' OR promo_code ~ '%\W%' AND promo_code !~ '%\s%'
    );

ALTER TABLE client
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_client_two
    CHECK (
        id ~ '%^[a-zA-Z0-9]*%' AND id !~ '%\s%',
        name ~ '%^[a-zA-Z]*%',
        promo_code ~ '%^[a-zA-Z0-9]*%' OR promo_code !~ '%^[a-zA-Z0-9]*%' 
            AND promo_code !~ '%\s%'
    );
```

rd_nielsen

```
ALTER TABLE client
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_client_one
    CHECK (
        id ~ '.+\w+.+' AND id !~ '.+\s+.+',
        name ~ '.+\w+.+' AND name !~ '.+\d+.+',
        promo_code ~ '.+\w+.+' OR promo_code ~ '.+\W+.+' 
            AND promo_code !~ '.+\s+.+'
    );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things worth mentioning:

- The `%` character is used by `LIKE` expressions as a zero-or-more wildcard. The regex equivalent is `.*`.
- If you want to match the entire string, then you need to anchor the start and end with `^` and `$`.

  - Conversely, unanchored patterns behave as though there were wildcards on both ends; for example, `\s` is the same as `^.*\s.*$`.
- `\w` matches underscores, and `\s` matches tabs and newlines, which you probably don't want to allow.
- The `~*` operator performs case-insensitive matching, letting you simplify `[A-Za-z]` to `[a-z]`.

With all of that in mind:

```
id ~* '^[a-z0-9]{18}$'
name ~* '^[a-z ]*$'
promo_code !~ '\s'
```

If you want to make sure that `name` isn't completely blank, use `^[a-z ]+$` instead.

The `promo_code` check will allow much more than just "symbols"; Unicode contains a lot of control codes and non-printable characters which don't count as "space". You might want to use an explicit whitelist instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something like your expressions will work, but your expressions contain a mixture of the SQL multiple-character wildcard ("%") and regular expression syntax.  You should eliminate the "%" characters and modify the regexes as necessary.  For example,

```
'%\w%'
```

should be

```
'.*\w*.*'
```

If the column is non-nullable, then `\w*` should be `\w+` instead.  Other expressions should be modified similarly.

Comment: Yes, your edit looks good in that it contains legitimate regexes.  The CHECK syntax uses commas to separate the expressions for different column, but `AND` should be used instead.  Or you could use three different CHECK expressions instead.

Comment: You don't need the `.*` at the beginning and the end of the pattern.

Comment: @LaurenzAlba: Ah, yes, you're right for the `'\w'` pattern.  It should be included for the `!~ '.*\s.*'` expression.